# PHP / Laravel Not Accepting .upd Files As A File

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

I need to upload update files for Android device updates. I need to upload two file extentions, first is .apk and the second is .upd. I have no problem with .apk but when I'm trying upload .upd files, it doesn't event get passed from validation.

[image]

I also tried it with simple PHP script, it only seems name and errors:

[image: php]

I couldn't find anyting on uploading .udp files with PHP or Laravel. I'd appreciatethe help, thank you very much.

Here is validation method:

```
private function validateRequest($request)
    {
        $fields  = [
            'file_type' => 'required',
            'update_file' => 'required|file',
            'swid' => 'required',
            'software' => 'required',
            'box_name' => 'required',
            'apk_version' => 'sometimes|required',
            'dongle_firmware_version' => 'sometimes|required',
            'change_log' => 'required',
        ];

        return Validator::make($request->all(), $fields )
            ->setAttributeNames([
                'file_type' => 'File type',
                'swid' => 'Software ID',
                'software' => 'Software',
                'box_name' => 'Box name',
                'apk_version' => 'Android version',
                'dongle_firmware_version' => 'Dongle firmware version',
                'change_log' => 'Change log',
                'update_file' => 'Update file'
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error codes are [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). Yours is `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`:

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.

If you need to upload larger files, just allow a larger size ;-)